# Removing variable text between braces from a string

Tags: tcl

I need to remove all text between the braces `{` and `}` (the braces included) and I don't know in advance which text is between them nor how long the text is.

Example:

```
AA {some text here } BB { some other text here } CC
```

should become:

```
AA BB CC
```

Comment: I'm assuming `original text` was not part of your text.

Comment: Are there going to be nested braces? If you've got nested braces, things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regsub here:

```
set filtered [regsub -all {\{.*?\}} $s ""]
```

Or, treat the string as a list of lists, and remove the sublists is length > 1

```
set filtered [lmap word $s {if {[llength $word] == 1} then {set word} else continue}]
```

Comment: Your `regsub` option is better.